# Sub reports Overlapping

Tags: crystal-reports, report, overlapping, subreport

I am having an issue when I try to add various reports inside the same section on Crystal Reports. This is the way I want the report to look like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wy3T.jpg).

My problem is on section 3. Whenever Sub report #5 grows, it overlaps with Sub Report #6. I know I can prevent that by placing Sub Report #6 inside another separated section, but that's not the way it should be.

Answer (score 0):

When you put subreports one directly below the other, and the upper one 'grows', you will see the behavior you describe.   The only alternatives if keeping them both in the same section :   place the lower one far enough down to not be impacted by the upper sub reports growth, or fix the upper sub report so it cant grow.    Been there, many times.   Those are your choices.